# insert...select statement in postgresql combining inserted values from php with a select statement

Tags: php, postgresql

I have seen some SO posts on how to insert selected values, but they are always in cases where all inserted values will come from the select statement. I am struggling to insert data that is partially provided by a php call and partially provided by a select statement. Here is what I would like to do:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO deals (latitude, longitude, interested, id, the_geom) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, SELECT the_geom FROM userlocs WHERE id=$3)";
$rs = pg_query_params($con, $query, array($latitudeS, $longitudeS, $id_pg , $id_add));
```

This is giving me the following not very helpful error:

```
 pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 1: ...interested, id, the_geom) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, SELECT the... ^ in /var/www/html/join.php on line 30
```

Is it possible to do what I would like to do? If so, how do I modify my syntax?

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: try `$query = "INSERT INTO deals (latitude, longitude, interested, id, the_geom) VALUES SELECT $1, $2, $3, $4, the_geom FROM userlocs WHERE id=$3";`

Comment: @Sean thanks for the suggestion, but this is giving me the same "syntax error" message.

Comment: it looks like postgresql does not use the `VALUES` when doing `INSERT ... SELECT`, so try `$query = "INSERT INTO deals (latitude, longitude, interested, id, the_geom) SELECT $1, $2, $3, $4, the_geom FROM userlocs WHERE id=$3";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest fix is to just put your `SELECT` statement in parentheses

```sql
INSERT INTO deals (latitude, longitude, interested, id, the_geom) 
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, (SELECT the_geom FROM userlocs WHERE id = $3))
```

Here is a **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b1544/1)** demo

Depending on whether you always expect a value coming from `userlocs` or not you can also use `INSERT ... SELECT` syntax in one of two ways

```sql
INSERT INTO deals (latitude, longitude, interested, id, the_geom) 
SELECT $1, $2, $3, $4, the_geom FROM userlocs WHERE id = $3
```

or

```sql
INSERT INTO deals (latitude, longitude, interested, id, the_geom) 
SELECT $1, $2, $3, $4, (SELECT the_geom FROM userlocs WHERE id = $3)
```

Comment: maybe `max(the_geom)` helping.

Comment: @ColourDalnet For what possible reason one would want to use an aggregate in this case?

Comment: if have more than 1 results.

Comment: @ColourDalnet Fair enough. But it only make sense if `id` for some reason is not the PK. A better alternative in that situation might be to use `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Yes, that is just the case id is not primary key, for example many-to-many relationship table. `LIMIT 1` is better combined with `ORDER BY` :)