# How to do a select statement in a insert, while in php

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, insert

I am working in PostgreSQL with a web application in PHP. The first query you see works just fine. The second query doesn't work, and causes some minor visual problems on the page, like an image to not load in.

IF I replace the SELECT statement with a number, like 1, the page will load correctly and like normal. The image will also load correctly.

I did test the $userID and $newJarName variables and found them to be correct, but as a safeguard, I also replaced them with static numbers and names and found that I still got the problem page.

I tried putting the select statement into its own variable, as well as the whole query into its own variable, and neither of those ideas worked.

I am thinking that I must have a problem with the syntax in my statement somewhere, but I can't tell. I did visit this page and had no luck.

[insert...select statement in postgresql combining inserted values from php with a select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161976/insert-select-statement-in-postgresql-combining-inserted-values-from-php-with)

```
function insertNewJar($newJarName, $userID, $db){
            $db->query(
                "INSERT into jars (jar_owner_id, jar_total, jar_active, jar_name)
                VALUES (
                        '$userID',
                        0,
                        true,
                        '$newJarName')"
                    );

                //linkJar($newJarName, $userID, $db);
                //$select = "(SELECT jar_id FROM jars WHERE jar_owner_id = '$userID' AND jar_name = '$newJarName')";



                $db->query(
                    "INSERT INTO users_jars (user_id, jar_id)
                    VALUES(
                        '$userID',
                        (SELECT jar_id FROM jars WHERE jar_owner_id = $userID AND jar_name = '$newJarName')
                    )"
                );  


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use prepared statements if you want to use parameters.
The queries are both susceptible to sql injection.

With PDO it would look something like that:

```php
$sth = $dbh->prepare('
    INSERT INTO users_jars (user_id, jar_id)
    VALUES(?, (SELECT jar_id FROM jars WHERE jar_owner_id = ? AND jar_name = ?))
');
$sth->execute(array($userID, $userID, $newJarName));
```

I dont know what type your `$db` is so i'm just guessing...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, totally slipped my mind.

Comment: but i guess it did not solve your problem... you may want to add more information about the query that does not work for you. The error message you get from postgress would help. Also maybe the schema for the 2 tables used.

Comment: I'll get a chance to work on it later today, and hopefully, a prepared statement will fix it. If not I will update with those additional details.